# Filtering data without refreshing the page

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to replicate a full website, with restaurants of different genres.

My home.blade.php is a list of all restaurants as it comes from the controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $restaurants = Restaurant::all();

        return view("test", compact("restaurants"));
    }
```

My idea is having an input in home.blade.php and real time rendering of only the restaurants of that genre. If i write "Pizza" it will show me all restaurants that make pizza, WITHOUT refreshing the page.

The database/migration/relation  are already done.

What should i be looking into?

Comment: To filter data without refresh you need to do it with javascript or some framework js based. With laravel you can do a search input, and than you can get back the view with filtered data, but this last solution is refreshing the page.

Comment: you should look at 
datatable 
or when typing just remove other rwos that doesn't has pizza word for example

Comment: You will need implement a reactive framework in your frontend, like React, Vue, Javascript or some similar. You could get the data from the server and insert or replace some html section.

Comment: You have 2 choices:

1) Get all results at once and filter them with javascript

2) Create an API and fetch them asynchronously (which still requires javascript knowledge)

Comment: There is this new package called Livewire which you can use in laravel to do these kind of stuff, other frontend frameworks are pretty awesome but livewire is close to laravel and blade without the hassle of learning a new framework